# Is the tone wrongly used in 违章与事故同在?

Tags: word-choice

I heard this on the bus in a Chinese city, the full being "违章与事故同在，守纪与安全永存".

The couplet seems to follow the pattern of 落霞与孤鹜齐飞,秋水共长天一色, but the tone sounds weird or even funny.

As far as the phrase 同在 is concerned, it often is used in a commendatory sense, like 上帝与你同在.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

同在(be with each other) doesn't match 永存(last forever)

违章与事故同在，守纪与安全永存". is better changed to "事故与违章共存，安全与守纪同在" (Accidents and violations coexist, safety and discipline always be with each other)

与XX同在 is indeed often used in a commendatory sense because we often wish to be with a positive figure or idea

Billions of people wish to be with God, justice, or happiness, none wishes to be with the Devil, injustice, or sadness

Comment: 同在 doesn't need to match 永存

Comment: The point is  "last forever" doesn't even fit in the context, 守纪与安全 can last forever without one another

Comment: 白話: 违章与事故(總是相互聯結)同枝而在，守纪与安全(是)永保生存(之道)."

Comment: 白話: 违章会导致事故，守纪会带来安全

Comment: That's not the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

落霞与孤鹜齐飞,秋水共长天一色 comes from the Chinese classic [滕王阁序](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%BB%95%E7%8E%8B%E9%98%81%E5%BA%8F/480325). It is an article / essay type literary work, which is a lot more relaxed than poetry or ci.

Therefore, the derived reminder 违章与事故同在，守纪与安全永存 does not have restrictions in tones, rhymes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. "`同在` used in a commendatory sense"---No, `同在` is not a commendatory term strictly speaking.
2. `违章与事故同在，守纪与安全永存`---A It's not strictly a couplet, just a jingle. And It's very nice that you can feel funny from it, that's exactly what it's about, funny to to impress.
3. There's a couple of lines very similar to it in the movie `《流浪地球》`:`道路千万条，安全第一条，行车不规范，亲人两行泪！`, Even the last sentence deliberately does not rhyme to deepen the impression, let people remember safety first.